# QBMS PayPage "Try a Test Transaction" page is gone

Tags: testing, credit-card, intuit-partner-platform

May 15 2013 noon PDT

In the Intuit Partner Platform under payment solutions - Hosted PayPage 
The "Try a Test Transaction" 
link: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/030_qbms/0030_Get_Set_Up/5._Try_a_Test_Transaction
shows a 404 not found.

It worked last week.

Is there any hope for a test page?
-mort

Comment: Yep - looks broken. Let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that page was moved to:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0030_get_set_up/5._try_a_test_transaction

I was not able to complete a transaction from that page though, I always get a "Problem Retrieving Xml Data" error.